# MYSQL query to access only column- header names

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

I want to display only my column names of a table, and not the other information. I tried the suggestions on other answers, but it didn't seem to work for me. The table is dynamic hence I can't access the fields beforehand. I am using a MYSQL database and my Django execute command is as follows:

```
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('SHOW COLUMNS FROM %s' % table_name)
        column = cursor.fetchall()
```

Can someone please help me figure out the change required to get only the column-header names, and not the entire information of the table.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA metadata virtual database. Query as
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='schema_name' AND `TABLE_NAME`='your_table';

Comment: Yeah, I can do that and it works on the MYSQL workbench. But when I try to do it using Django, I'm not sure how to reference the table_schema as it's already linked to the Django app. When I leave that field empty, another error pops up saying "unknown column 'your_table' in where clause"

Comment: If you do not have multiple schemas available in database, you may try adding the fixed schema value in query itself and only use dynamic values for table name.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks!